# materials rendered as black in BI

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

suddenly all my objects are rendered as black, i'm in Blender render.
any tips?
cheers
[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of material panel ? Are material nodes used for this material ? (check in Node Editor with object selected).

Comment: it looks like there is no lamp in this layer but... as @MrZak said, that could be useful to have at least the description of the material

Answer (score 4):

I accidentally hid the lamp.

[image]

That's why all of the objects turned black.